# Why isn't Xdebug working with Chrome, but it is with the internal PhpStorm browser?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

My setup has local files running on WAMP.  I have configured Xdebug to work fine when I try to set a breakpoint using the PhpStorm internal browser.  However, I can't seem to make it work when using Edge or Chrome.

I have the Xdebug extension installed and turned on in the browser.  The little "bug" is Green and if I hover over it, it says, "Debugging is enabled, has access to this site."

Within PhpStorm I have the "listening" icon on and green. Whereas, with the PhpStorm browser I can step through a program just fine and the results show up in the PhpStorm console, if I run the program in Edge the script runs, but nothing pauses and nothing is sent to the PhpStorm console.

I assume this is a configuration error, but I haven't got a clue.  Let me know if there are any settings/files you need to see to help.  Thanks in advance.

******edit********
This is the phpinfo section on Xdebug:

```
xdebug
Version 3.1.1
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business
Enabled Features
(through 'xdebug.mode' setting)
Feature Enabled/Disabled    Docs
Development Helpers ✔ enabled   
Coverage    ✘ disabled  
GC Stats    ✘ disabled  
Profiler    ✘ disabled  
Step Debugger   ✘ disabled  
Tracing ✘ disabled  
Optional Features
Compressed File Support yes (gzip)
Clock Source    GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.client_discovery_header  no value    no value
xdebug.client_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.client_port  9003    9003
xdebug.cloud_id no value    no value
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_params   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms   200 200
xdebug.coverage_enable  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.default_enable   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.discover_client_host Off Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.log  c:/wamp64/logs/xdebug.log   c:/wamp64/logs/xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level    7   7
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.mode develop develop
xdebug.output_dir   c:/wamp64/tmp   c:/wamp64/tmp
xdebug.overload_var_dump    (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_connect_back  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_enable    (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_host  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log_level (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_mode  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_port  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_timeout   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.start_upon_error default default
xdebug.start_with_request   default default
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.use_compression  1   1
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

Comment: 1) Please show the whole `xdebug_info();` table (for Xdebug v3; for Xdebug v2 that would be the whole Xdebug section of `phpinfo()`) captured in that "not-working" browser. 2) Maybe different URLs are used etc? Double check this as well. 3) Also open browser's Dev Tools, Network panel and see if Xdebug cookie is actually present in the request. Sometimes it may be some glitch in a browser/extension so deleting all caches and properly restarting the browser can help.

Comment: P.S. As I understand this is yours? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-64984

Comment: LazyOne, thanks for your suggestions.  I have posted the xdebug_info() into the original post as an edit as it was too long for a comment.  I will check the other items now.

Comment: This is the output from the console of PhpStorm: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.33\php.exe -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_port=9000 -dxdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1 C:\wamp64\www\Test\index.php
998999
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: This is the url when the program is run from PhpStorm in Edge: http://localhost/Test/index.php

Comment: LazyOne - I think this is the info you wanted regarding the cookies.  I got it from the Network->Cookies tab in devtools: 
Phpstorm-d8f5e4e2 d5682b55-ffa3-4638-ac74-1c6dc6cee8db localhost / 2032-01-13T17:53:36.403Z 53 ✓  Strict  Medium XDEBUG_SESSION PHPSTORM localhost / 2023-01-17T01:41:58.000Z 22     Medium

Comment: Looking at the same thing in firefox I saw one thing that looks interesting.  The XDEBUG_SESSION cookie has a value of XDEBUG_ECLIPSE.  Is this appropriate?  I don't think I have Eclipse installed unless it is part of the PhpStorm or WAMP install.

Comment: 1) the `xdebug_info()` / `phpinfo()` results -- they must be taken in THE SAME environment where you are trying to debug: a web page or a CLI. This is because A) you can have different configs for those environments and B) PhpStorm can pass needed params for CLI but have no control over 3rd party web server (in terms of actual Xdebug params).

Comment: 2) Your *"phpinfo section on Xdebug:"* -- it **clearly** shows that the debugging is DISABLED -- `Step Debugger   ✘ disabled` . Look into your Xdebug config and make it enabled. 3) *"This is the output from the console of PhpStorm: "* -- Yes, here PhpStorm passes all most needed params, so even if you do not have them set already it will override them. That's why the same environment is important here.

Comment: *"The XDEBUG_SESSION cookie has a value of XDEBUG_ECLIPSE. Is this appropriate?"* PhpStorm does not really care about the value of this parameter (except for specific Run/Debug Configuration type). XDEBUG_ECLIPSE is a default value and should work just fine.